# Any software to send for right click email attachment

Tags: email, software-rec, attachments

I want to send various files as email attachment  but just right click on it and then send to email.

Is there any software for that except backup to gmail as  i use yahoo.

Comment: What is your email client? "software" is not a very informative tag.

Comment: You might consider posting your OS.

Comment: OS windows 7 ultimate

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP has that functionality. Just select the files, right-click, copy-to and then select email.

Comment: but i don't have outlook , i want something to work without outlook

Comment: Well,  you can install Thunderbird :-)
(or rephrase your question to indicate that you want to use a web based solution or something)

Comment: You could use Windows Live Mail

Comment: i want minimum steps like right click on file and then send thats it. i don't to manually copile the email and then send. just like software backup to gmail . send file with one click

Comment: @Moorage And... uhm... so... you have a specific address you want to send to every time?